# How to rotate image and save in media store in android

Tags: android

I am taking a picture using a custom front camera in android, but saving the image in the wrong orientation. Can anybody tell me how to avoid this or how to rotate the image and save it in the media store in android? Can anybody provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rotate the image:

```
Bitmap bmp = getOriginalBitmap();
Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
rotateMatrix.postRotate(degreeToRotate);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
```

Then you should be able to save it like so:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), rotatedBitmap, "My bitmap", "My rotated bitmap");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the orientation from the [EXIF data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), like so:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(sourceFileName);     //Since API Level 5
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

Similarly, you should use `setAttribute()` to change the orientation.